# Insert javascript to link not working as expected

Tags: links, javascript

Using insert javascript on link field, adds javascript code to a tag in href with return false which is added automatically and because of it mistake appears and if manually delete return false everything is okey.

Comment: What code you use to render the link?

Comment: fields.items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id} >
              <Link
                field={item.fields.Link}
                onClick={e => this.onClick(e, item.fields.Link.value.href)}
              />
            </li>
          ))

Comment: @John Vein - Were you able to fix this? I am also in the same problem and was looking for a fix on it.

Comment: Linking this to the better worded question